# Python: win32gui.SetForegroundWindow

Tags: python, handle

I have just written simple script to launch an applciation and I am trying to use "SendKeys" module to send keystrokes to this application. There is one `"Snapshot"` button, but I cant get Python to click  `"Snapshot"` button, as the new window is not in focus. So I am planning to use Win32gui module's `win32gui.FindWindow` and `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow` functionality. But it gives me `error- invalid handle`. My app name is "DMCap"

Here is code snippet in Python:

```
handle = win32gui.FindWindow(0, "DMCap")  //paassing 0 as I dont know classname 
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle)  //put the window in foreground
```

Can anyone help me? Is this Python code correct? Can I send handle directly like this?

Answer (score 6):

Your code should run just fine as-is, IF there is truly a window titled "DMCap." To get a list of handles and titles, run the code below:

```
import win32gui
def window_enum_handler(hwnd, resultList):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) != '':
        resultList.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

def get_app_list(handles=[]):
    mlst=[]
    win32gui.EnumWindows(window_enum_handler, handles)
    for handle in handles:
        mlst.append(handle)
    return mlst

appwindows = get_app_list()
for i in appwindows:
    print i
```

This will produce a list of tuples containing handle, title pairs.

Comment: My present focus is on Excel:   In testing your solution with various extensions, for Excel workbooks I noticed that their titles always appeared in the form, "filename.ext - Excel", where the path did not come into play.  For an xlsx file named test1.xlsx, regardless of path, the title would be "test1.xlsx - Excel".  Can I rely on " - Excel" being added to the filename.ext, or is there a better "rule" I am unaware of?