# Is there a way to check if a program is open and then if it is, switch to it, and if it isn't, open it?

Tags: python, google-chrome, ioerror

I'm currently writing a program which needs to check if a program is open before deciding to switch to it or open a new one. For example, a  chrome short cut should check if chrome is already open. If it isn't then it should open a new chrome window but if it is then it should just show the existing chrome window/tab. Is there a way to write a function to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a program is open I would suggest a library named [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil).

The switch of the window is more complicated and depends on the OS, for example in Windows you have to create (or get) an handle for that window and then call the OS API to change it, this is simply made using win32gui, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770909/python-win32gui-setforegroundwindow).